# Connect bridges without crossing - dynamic programming algorithms design

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Considering a 2-D map with a horizontal river passing through its centre. There are n cities
on the northern bank with x-coordinates a(1) ... a(n) and n cities on the southern bank
with x-coordinates b(1) ... b(n). I want to connect as many north-south pairs of cities
as possible with bridges such that no two bridges cross. When connecting cities, I can
only connect city i on the northern bank to city i on the southern bank. How can I solve this using dynamic programming[image: Visualization of problem]?

Comment: You can solve this using **integer programming**

Answer (score 1):

Two lines `i` and `j` cross if and only if `a(i) < a(j) and b(i) > b(j)` or `a(i) > a(j) and b(i) < b(j)`. Looking at the lines in a solution sorted by `a` value, then, there are no crossings if and only if the corresponding `b` values are increasing. Therefore we should sort the `(a, b)` pairs by `a` and compute a longest increasing subsequence on `b`.

Comment: One of the conditions of the question is that I can't change the positions of I and j

Comment: @youssefmanyalawy Right, the sort moves the elements in tandem. So if the example looks something like a = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5] and b = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4], then we swap the second and third positions in both arrays to get a' = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and b' = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4], so the x-coordinates of the lines are (1, 2) (2, 3) (4, 5), which works out to lines 1, 3, 4 on the original array.

Comment: Okay but as I said, we can't change the elements' positions and we should only connect the numbers alike

Comment: @youssefmanyalawy another way to think about the sort is that it's relabeling both endpoints of each bridge the same way, so that the set of bridges stays the same.

Comment: This makes an unstated assumption that the `y` coordinate for each set of cities (north and south) is constant. Although I agree with that assumption, the [meandering river shown in the drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3HbC.png) doesn't support it.